# Unable to retrieve leaderboards in Google Play Games for Android

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying to write a custom Activity to show leaderboards on my game in a way that the look and feel is more integrated with the style of my app than the default Leaderboards provided in Google Play Games Services. However, I am having issues retrieving data.

In order to get, for instance, All time Public Top Scores on my global leaderboard, I use the following code:

```
protected void getTopScores() {
    PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult> pendingScores = Games.
            Leaderboards.loadTopScores(
                googleApiClient,
                GLOBAL_LEADERBOARD_ID,
                LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, 
                LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 
                25, 
                true);
    processPendingResult(pendingScores);
}

protected void processPendingResult(PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult> pendingScores){
    pendingScores.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult loadScoresResult) {
            List<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScores = extractScores(loadScoresResult);
            notifyScoresLoaded(leaderboardScores);
        }
    });
}

protected List<LeaderboardScore> extractScores(Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult loadScoresResult) {
    LeaderboardScoreBuffer buffer = loadScoresResult.getScores();
    List<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScores = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.getCount(); i++){
        leaderboardScores.add(buffer.get(i));
    }
    return leaderboardScores;
}
```

However, the `LeaderboardScoreBuffer` is empty. I made sure that my profile is public on the Google Play Games app, but still it doesn't appear.

Besides, if I try to use `LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_SOCIAL` instead, I receive a single value corresponding to the logged in user, but I have some other users play-testing the game who I've added to my Google+ circles.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It might by the time you are calling the leaderboard scores are not loaded yet. You need to have some callbacks.

Comment: The code looks like it should work.  If you test with the standard leaderboard UI do you see the scores?  It most likely is a permissions thing where public visibility can take up to 24hr to update.  Social should be faster but make sure the profile permissions are set correctly for the game.